# I have a wind simulation in Unity, and i need to rotate an arrow to show the wind direction

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, quaternion

I have this code that creates random vectors, which are used in the AddForce to push rigid bodies around.

```
var angle = Random.Range(-WindAngle, WindAngle);
var quaternion = Quaternion.Euler(0, angle, 0);
var newDirection = quaternion * direction;
direction = newDirection;
```

I also need an arrow that will rotate to show the direction, but i can't get it to work.

I use

```
Arrow.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(windarea.direction, new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
```

but it rotates on the Y instead of the Z. I tried different vectors, but it just makes it worse.

Comment: I've linked this to a [previous question about how to make LookRotation work with axes other than the Unity-standard "z forward, y up" convention](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/199842/39518). If you need help applying that to your use case, please edit your question to show how you've tried using it, with what object (show us a screenshot with the local transform axes visible so we can see how it's oriented), and how the output is differing from what you expect.